# How to reduce wsdl data in php script

Tags: php, api, wsdl

I use simple php script, which contains API (wsdl)

```
<?
 $client = new SoapClient('http://nbg.gov.ge/currency.wsdl');
 print ("Exchange Rates: USD - ");
 print $client->GetCurrency('USD').'₾/';
?>
```

This is exchange rate. I receive 4 digit after dot / USD -  1.2345
but want only 2 digits after dot like USD - 1.23
Is this possible ?

Comment: Does [`number_format()`](http://php.net/number_format) could helps you?

Answer (score 0):

Number formatting has nothing to do with the web service. Check http://php.net/number_format for documentation.

```
echo number_format( '1.123456789', 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use php number_format() function.

> number_format(1,2,3,4)

```
<?
$client = new SoapClient('http://nbg.gov.ge/currency.wsdl');
print ("Exchange Rates: USD - ");
print number_format($client->GetCurrency('USD'), 2, ',', '.').'₾/';
?>
//Ex output = Exchange Rates: USD - 2,47₾/
```

1. for your number / currency
2. for decimal for ex. 2 depoint output '2.22'
3. for decimal point like ',/.'
4. thousands seperator like './,'